# weird characters instead of an image when dispalying from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a blob image from mySQL, and I'm getting weird characters instead.

To insert data I use:

```
  if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name( image )VALUES('$data')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

To display:

```
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "There is nothing";
}

while($rows= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

//header('Content-type: image/jpg'); 
 echo $rows['image'];

?>
```

How can I fix that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's best practice to not store images in your database. Store them in a folder instead.

Second, you are seeing the raw data of the image in ASCII.

To answer your question if you must store images in a database, make a new php file.

```
header('content-type: image/png'); // Use a variable for the image type
// Code here to select a single image from the database.
// Echo the database value.
```

Call the picture with

```
<img src="link_to_php_file.php" alt="" />
```

Comment: +1 for remark about storing images in a database. A database is really just a glorified file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an image header, like:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png"); // or image/jpeg or image/gif
```

Keep in mind that you can only show one image per time and nothing else.

If you want to show multiple images on a webpage you will need to simply link to them:

```
<img src="getimage.php?id=1234" />
<img src="getimage.php?id=1235" />
<img src="getimage.php?id=1236" />
```

Where getimage.php contains the code that will send the Content-Type header and fetch the data BLOB from MySQL.

Comment: On the page I'm typing:`<img src="show_image.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" width="160" heigh="120"/><br/>` And in the show_image.php this: `<?php
include("../content/db_connect.php");
$tbl_name="gallery"; // Table name


$id = $_GET['id'];

if(!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)){
     die("Please select your image!");
}else{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
     echo $content;
}

?>`  And get no result(( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define 'no result'. Maybe you need to send an image/jpEg header? Do you get any (binary) output at all if you remove the header?